# invoking method with two same parameters returns two different results

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, keynotfoundexception

I have a simple project, using MVC pattern, ET and WCF. It uses Dijkstra to find paths between cities. [This is the class itself.](http://paste2.org/5HM8Imcw)

However, when calling `FindPathFromCityToCity()` with two same lists in the `map` object, same `from` and `to`, when it's on a normal console application it returns the desired result. However, when used from WCF, it fails on line 39 with exception `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`.

In order to check whether if my input is incorrect I added that writing to a txt file (line 17 to 27) and this is what it results (TL;DR - both are exactly the same):

Console:

```
COUNT: 14 - RANGE 120
FROM: Aalborg - TO: Copenhagen
C: Frederikshavn - E: 2 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Aalborg - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Hobro - E: 4 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Randers - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Viborg - E: 8 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Aarhus - E: 8 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Herning - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Vejle - E: 8 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Kolding - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Odense - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Aabenraa - E: 2 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Koge - E: 4 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Copenhagen - E: 2 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Soro - E: 4 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
```

WCF:

```
COUNT: 14 - RANGE 120
FROM: Aalborg - TO: Copenhagen
C: Frederikshavn - E: 2 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Aalborg - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Hobro - E: 4 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Randers - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Viborg - E: 8 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Aarhus - E: 8 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Herning - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Vejle - E: 8 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Kolding - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Odense - E: 6 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Aabenraa - E: 2 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Koge - E: 4 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Copenhagen - E: 2 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
C: Soro - E: 4 - T: BLL.BatteryCenter
```

Can someone see any reason for that to happen?

---

**EDIT:**

I did further tests, printing everything possible of the objects with this snippet and [there is **no** difference](http://www.diffchecker.com/4yzrr5bl) in the objects (except hash of course):

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\log\check.txt", true))
{
    foreach (var m in map.Stations)
    {
        file.WriteLine(" --- {0} - {1} - {2} - {3} --- ", m.name, m.Edgelist.Count, m.GetType(), m.GetHashCode());
        foreach(var e in m.Edgelist)
        {
            file.WriteLine();
            file.WriteLine(" # {0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", e.BatteryStation.name, e.BatteryStation1.name, e.distance, e.edgeID);
            file.WriteLine(" + {0} - {1} - {2}", e.BatteryStation.GetType(), e.BatteryStation.stationID, e.BatteryStation.GetHashCode());
            file.WriteLine(" - {0} - {1} - {2}", e.BatteryStation1.GetType(), e.BatteryStation1.stationID, e.BatteryStation1.GetHashCode());
        }
        file.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all hinges on the mechanics of the `BatteryCenter` object.

The calling code is passing it in as a parameter, and the function is using it as a key in the map.

Have you overridden the functions `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `BatteryCenter`?

If not, then the dictionary lookup will be searching for **that exact** object. Not a `BatteryCenter` with all of the same fields, but the object with the same reference.

The WCF client would be passing in an equivalent but nonetheless different `BatteryCenter`, which the dictionary is failing to find.

Once you add overrides for `BatteryCenter.Equals` and `BatteryCenter.GetHashCode` this would probably work.

eg

```
public override int GetHashCode() 
{
     return this.stationID.GetHashCode() ^ this.name.GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
{
     if(Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
     {
          return true;
     }
     BatteryStation other = obj as BatteryStation;
     if(Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
     {
         return false;
     }
     return ((this.stationID == other.stationID) && (this.name == other.name));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that both lists will contain different objects, but how does this matter anyway? Both lists aren't connected anyhow, it is supposed to work even if I manually create the `map` object and add `BatteryCenter`s to it, isn't it?

There is (or at least I do not know of such) no logic in that if it's submitted by WCF or normal client, both ways the list with maps is from the database. 

Can you explain what exactly and how would I overwrite on `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. I am unaware of such resolution?